# How to define the color's shade in qtquickcontrols2.conf?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to define the style of my application in the [`qtquickcontrols2.conf`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-configuration.html) file like this:

```
[Controls]
Style=Material

[Material]
Theme=Light
Variant=Dense
Accent=DeepOrange
Primary=Indigo
Foreground=Blue
Background=Grey
```

For each of the four colors (`Accent`, `Primary`, `Foreground` and `Background`) I want to specify the [shade](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html#pre-defined-shades) as well. However I cannot find the syntax I should use.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible. You can set it on the root object though:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    // ...

    Material.foreground: Material.color(Material.Blue, Material.ShadeA100)
}
```

This will propagate to every other control in the application.